# Small challenge. Comparing sum of 3 individual arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The code suppose to sum every individual array. Afterwards it can be use to compare which sum is the biggest or the lowes. Do anybody knows shorter way or more efficient?

```
int[] route1 = {12,34,21,46,25};
int[] route2 = {24,1,5,64,10,15,21};
int[] route3 = {1,13,15,16};

public static String shortestRoute(int [] route1, int [] route2, int [] route3){
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum3 = 0;

    int[][] arrays = {route1, route2, route3};

    //how to write shorter the part below???
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for(int i = 0; i<arrays.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<arrays[i].length; j++){

            if(i==0){
                sum1 += arrays[i][j];
            }else if(i==1){
                sum2 += arrays[i][j];
            }else{
                sum3 += arrays[i][j];
            }          
        }   
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: The code works, so this is not the appropriate site for the question. Better would be on the [code-review stackexchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but if you do ask there, be sure to go through their help files to be sure that the question is asked appropriately.

Comment: You could start by using an array for sums too and removing unnecessary `if`s

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Java 8, summing an array can be done in a single line of code, letting you remove all loops and multi-dimensional array handling from your program:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(route1).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit more detailed example of single line solution for longest/shortest route calculation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] route1 = {12, 34, 21, 46, 25};
    int[] route2 = {24, 1, 5, 64, 10, 15, 21};
    int[] route3 = {1, 13, 15, 16};

    shortestRoute(route1,route2,route3);
    longestRoute(route1,route2,route3);
}
private static long shortestRoute(int[]... routes) {
    return Arrays.stream(routes)
            .mapToInt(value -> Arrays.stream(value).sum()).min().getAsInt();
}
private static long longestRoute(int[]... routes) {
    return Arrays.stream(routes)
            .mapToInt(value -> Arrays.stream(value).sum()).max().getAsInt();
}
```